# How do I interact with $title, $breadcrumbs, and $action_links within a process or preprocess function?

Tags: theming

I'm using a Bootstrap subtheme, with a custom page.tpl.php override.  Within the template file, I see there are variables for $title, $breadcrumbs, and $action_links.

If I wanted to access these inside of a preprocess or process function, let's say to modify the title based on whether or not there is content in a given region, how would I do that?

They don't seem to be passed along in $variables like the rest of the page content.  $variables['title'] is not present.  Would I use API functions such as `drupal_set_title()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I manipulate breadcrumbs in page preprocess function. You can actually do this somewhere else, where you think it fits according to your needs.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function extremes_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // You can use preprocess hooks to modify the variables before they are passed
  // to the theme function or template file.

  //define breadcrumbs array
  $breadcrumb = array();
  $breadcrumb[] = l('SS','<front>');//add homepage first
  //if we are on one of my dynamic pages, we do this
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && !empty($variables['node']) && _is_dynamic_type($variables['node']->type)) { 
    if (!empty($variables['node']->field_term_reference)) {//we are gonna depend on a term ref field
      //get all parent terms
      $parents = array_reverse(taxonomy_get_parents_all($variables['node']->field_term_reference[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id']));
      //and add them to breadcrumb array
      foreach ($parents as $parent) {
        $breadcrumb[] = l($parent->name, 'taxonomy/term/' . $parent->tid);
      }
    }
    //set the breadcrumb
    drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
  }
  //if we are on a term listing page
  else if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && is_numeric(arg(2))) {//you can also check here, which vocabulary you want
    //easier this time
    $parents = array_reverse(taxonomy_get_parents_all(arg(2)));
    foreach ($parents as $parent) {
      $breadcrumb[] = l($parent->name, 'taxonomy/term/' . $parent->tid);
    }
    if (arg(3) && $type = taxonomy_term_machine_name_load(arg(3), 'vocab_name')) {
      $breadcrumb[] = l($type->name, request_path());
    }
    drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
  }

}
```

This sample uses [taxonomy_machine_name.module](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_machine_name) which uses the same system with pathauto and is very useful for loading taxonomy terms from url if you set up correctly.

For title, you can go with [drupal_set_title()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_title/7) and for action links [hook_menu_local_tasks_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/7).